# Xdebug connection with VSC with WSL2 and Docker

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug, wsl-2

I try to get Xdebug to work on my local machine and run into the following problem. Xdebug doesn't get a connection to VSCode.

My setup is using Docker containers on Windows 10 on the WSL and Visual Studio Code.

When I try Xdebug I get the following errors:

```
    [Step Debug] Creating socket for '192.168.16.1:9004', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).  
⚠️  [Step Debug] Could not connect to client host discovered through HTTP headers, connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9004. :-|   
⚠️  [Step Debug] Creating socket for 'localhost:9004', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29). 
⚠️  [Step Debug] Creating socket for 'localhost:9004', connect: Cannot assign requested address.    
  [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 192.168.16.1:9004 (from REMOTE_ADDR HTTP header), localhost:9004 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(`
```

[image: Xdebug error]

These are my settings:

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9004,
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "log": true,
            "hostname" : "localhost",
            "pathMappings": 
            {
                "/var/www/html/": "${workspaceRoot}/docker/wordpress/public/"             
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9004
        }
    ]  
}
```

php.ini

```
[xdebug]
#zend_extension = ./lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so
xdebug.start_with_request = trigger 
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.discover_client_host = 1
xdebug.log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.client_port = 9004
```

Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    g++ \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl \
    && touch /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini \
    && echo "memory_limit = 128M;\nupload_max_filesize = 64M\npost_max_size = 128M" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql \
    && pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

I already tested the port 9003 and it didn't work. When I check if there is a connection available with telnet it gets connected. I have also enabled the port on the firewall.

---

Edit: I have found a configuration that works for me based on the provided links from @LazyOne.

I updated the follwoing configs and use the browser extension.

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "log": true,
            "host" : //wsl ip
            "pathMappings": 
            {
                "/var/www/html/": "${workspaceRoot}/docker/wordpress/public/"             
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9003
        }
    ]  
}
```

php.ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = ./lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so
xdebug.start_with_request = trigger 
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.discover_client_host = 0
xdebug.log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.client_host = //wsl ip
```

Comment: Side note: your images are the same (1st image is wrong).

Comment: WSL2 changes the IP address on every reboot -- that's the main issue here. You need to get the right IP for Xdebug to use. Check these links as a starting points: 1) https://medium.com/@tomasbruckner/intellij-xdebug-with-wsl-2-docker-4224b6efb0bb 2) https://www.silverf0x00.com/setting-up-xdebug-for-phpstorm-on-windows-wsl2/ (use Xdebug v3 config params; these articles are still using v2 params)

Comment: @LazyOne Thx for the links and the hint with the images. I removed the duplicate.

I know use the dynamic ip with the environment variable.  I made some progress and now the eror changed to the following:

I tried using localhost and the ip address in the launch.json

  [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 2000 ms. Tried: 172.20.163.174:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(

Comment: 1) Does VSCode listens on that port when you are trying to debug? Use `netstat` or any alike GUI tool (that can show current connections: what app listens what port) to confirm that. 2) I assume firewall allows incoming connection from WSL to the host OS. P.S. I personally do not use neither VSCode or WSL so cannot give more precise advice here :(, only general ones.

Answer (score 3):

To configure XDebug 3 + WSL2 + Docker in Visual Studio Code...

## Pre-requisites

1. Install WSL Extension (Microsoft official)
2. Install PHP Debug Extension (Xdebug official)
3. Create a Windows Defender Rule for WSL (see below)
4. Have xdebug extension enabled (`php -v` must show 'with Xdebug...' inside docker's container)

### Windows Defender Rule

1. Open Powershell as administrator
2. Run `New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName “WSL” -Direction Inbound -InterfaceAlias “vEthernet (WSL)” -Action Allow`

## Steps to configure VS Code

1. Make sure VSCode is connected to WSL and your project is opened within it
2. Click on the Run And Debug (Ctrl+Shift+D)
3. Create a new configuration using PHP option
4. Open `.vscode/launch.json` and add the highlighted lines

```json
"configurations": [
{
    ...
    "pathMappings": 
    {
        "/var/www/html/": "${workspaceRoot}/path/to/your/public/mapped/folder/"             
    },
    "hostname": "0.0.0.0"
```

Once you're done, create some breakpoints (ideally in your first index.php file), and click on the green play button to start listening for Xdebug connections.

## PHP.ini

Make sure your PHP/Xdebug settings inside your php container contains the following options:

```ini
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
xdebug.start_with_request=1
xdebug.connection_timeout_ms=2000
```

**Note 1**: the last line is just a precaution, in case your computer is too slow.

**Note 2**: this setting will enable xdebug in every request, and don't require any setup on your browser. Once you make it work, you can move forward for more advanced configurations, including browser cookies and [trigger option](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#start_with_request), to avoid slowing your system when xdebug is not needed.

In some docker images you can add a constant option in the compose.yaml file.

Alternativelly, you can run `php --ini` and map a new `something.ini` file with the content above inside one of the "Scan for additional .ini files in:" folders displayed when you ran this command.

## Troubleshooting

Make sure your VS Code is really listening to the port you've configured (9003 by default).

For doing so, log into the linux container, and install some iptools (`apt get update && apt install -y inetutils-ping netcat`).

Then you can run `nc -vz host.docker.internal 9003` or `ping host.docker.internal`.

You must see some message with "succeeded!" in it. Otherwise, it means your xdebug can't reach your host machine with VS Code for some reason.

Comment: Thanks @ricardo-martins.  I was struggling with this for hours and I followed your instructions and Xdebug works with VSC through Docker WSL

Answer (score 0):

Each of these messages has a link to the docs (icon on the right), have you read all of that?

Right now, Xdebug is telling you that it can't connect. That's either because the IDE isn't listening, or because Xdebug is trying to connect to the wrong IP address.

`xdebug.discover_client_host` almost never works for WSL2 (and Docker), so you will need to use `xdebug.client_host` instead to set the right IP address, and set `xdebug.discover_client_host=no`.

What the "right" IP address is, is going to depend on your setup, but IIRC, you can use `ipconfig /all` on a Windows command line (not in WSL2) to find out.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with this setup a lot. I've had a similiar issue/error, and I'm going to post it here as this question does well with google. What I've recently discovered is, when I run `docker compose up` when I'm not running `Listen for XDebug` in vscode, I get this error with Xdebug:

```
[Step Debug] Creating socket for 'host.docker.internal:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
```

But if I am running "Listen for Xdebug" when I do spin up the containers, it connects, no problems. I can then start and stop listening for Xdebug in vscode as much a I want.

This behaviour could be only due to a misconfiguration in my setup, but it might help someone and I'm just so pumped to be able to consistantly run Xdebug on my setup.